# java.awt.print.PrinterException: The handle is invalid

Tags: java, printing, network-printers

I'm implementing silent printing on network printers through Java Print Service and IcePDF.
I have added two network printers A and B to my development machine.

When I submit print job to printer A, it prints file without any issue, the same job submitted to printer B then it throws 
Exception in thread "main" **java.awt.print.PrinterException: The handle is invalid.**

```
at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob._startDoc(Native Method)
at sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob.startDoc(WPrinterJob.java:1249)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1371)
at org.tgslc.print.PDFRenderTest.main(PDFRenderTest.java:70)
```

print document type is PDF document.
Printer A is HP LaserJet 9050 PS
Printer B is IBM Infoprint 2190 PS High speed printer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The handle is invalid" message is not specific to Java. Try to print to that printer from other program (Notepad/Word) from the same computer. It could be problem with printer settings or driver.

Comment: you are correct. When I print from Notepad then the alert message says "The handle is invalid". But when I print PDF document it prints fine without any error message.

Comment: Driver issue at my development machine. Works fine at other machine.